# preg_replace doesn't allow me to put spaces in my search

Tags: php, html, search, preg-replace, search-engine

My code doesn't seem to let me put spaces in my search box if I searched "hello world" it would search it as this "helloworld". I'm using `preg_replace` so people aren't allowed to put other symbols like ("'!@#$%^&*()~`+-*//) none of those but letters. Why is it replacing spaces?

Code:

```
$search = preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$search);
```

Comment: your replace is removing everything that is not 0-9, a-z.

Comment: Space is also a character. And it's not between a-z nor 0-9, can you make an educated guess why it's being stripped?

Answer (score 1):

Okay let me break it down for you. As it is your regular expression looks for

```
[^0-9a-z]
```

^ - means negation in regexp (well not exactly, it means "everything but ..."), and then it is followed with two ranges: 0-9 and a-z. This means that any character which is not of those two exact sets will be caught by this expression. This includes arabic characters, special characters and spaces. In order to make it work as you want it, you will have to add space to the expression:

```
[^0-9a-z ]
```

You have to keep in mind that regular expressions are very literal and they give almost no leeway.